# How to implement Multi-DB Pattern with Slick 3.1 and DDD

Tags: scala, functional-programming, domain-driven-design, slick, ddd-repositories

I am reading [Functional And Reactive Domain Modeling](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-and-reactive-domain-modeling) by Debasish Ghosh and i want to refactor a CRUD application that it's actually on production.
I'm focusing on a first approach with Reader monad for DI, Repository pattern and ADT's for an app that manages equivalences values between applications (think of a value, understood in a certain way by some application and then query it's equivalent value for another system).

Debasish refers to repository pattern as a way for decoupling, so, in my case i need concrete implementations for Oracle and Postgresql and H2 for testing.
I have the following and very straightforward implementation (based on the book):

**Base `trait` for repositories:**

```
trait Repository[A, Id] {

  def query(id: Id): Try[Option[A]]
  def insert(a: A): Try[A]
  def update(a: A): Try[A]
  def delete(a: A): Try[A]

}
```

**Module for Equivalence Repository:**

```
trait EquivalenceRepository extends Repository[Equivalence, Long]{

  def query(id: Long): Try[Option[Equivalence]]
  def insert(a: Equivalence): Try[Equivalence]
  def update(a: Equivalence): Try[Equivalence]
  def delete(a: Equivalence): Try[Equivalence]

}
```

**And the *mid-way concrete* implementation with Slick:**

```
class EquivalenceOracleRepository extends EquivalenceRepository {

  def query(id: Long): Try[Option[Equivalence]] = {
    ???
  }

  def insert(a: Equivalence): Try[Equivalence] = {
    ???
  }

  def update(a: Equivalence): Try[Equivalence] = {
    ???
  }

  def delete(a: Equivalence): Try[Equivalence] = {
    ???
  }

}

private[repository] trait EquivalenceOracleDB{
  this: DBComponent =>

  import jdbcProfile.api._

  final case class EquivalenceDTO(
                                    originId: Int,
                                    equivalenceId: Int,
                                    creator: String,
                                    creationDate: Timestamp,
                                    isActive: Boolean
                                  )

  final class EquivalenceTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Equivalence](tag, "Equivalence"){

    def originId: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("ORIGIN_ID", O.SqlType("NUMBER(10)"))
    def equivalenceId: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("EQUIVALENCE_ID", O.SqlType("NUMBER(10)"))
    def creator: Rep[String] = column[String]("CREATOR", O.SqlType("NUMBER(10)"))
    def creationDate: Rep[Timestamp] = column[Timestamp]("CREATION_DATE", O.SqlType("TIMESTAMP(6)"))
    def isActive: Rep[Boolean] = column[Boolean]("IS_ACTIVE", O.SqlType("VARCHAR2(1)"))

    def pk: PrimaryKey = primaryKey("EQUIVALENCES_PK", (originId, equivalenceId))

    def * : ProvenShape[EquivalenceDTO] =
      (originId, equivalenceId, creator, creationDate, isActive) <> (EquivalenceDTO.tupled, EquivalenceDTO.unapply)

  }

  val table = TableQuery[EquivalenceTable]

}
```

Being the last one a concrete implementation for Oracle, you can see that the trait is expecting a DBComponent. This is a trait whose code it's inherited from the actual production application and tries to define the concrete Slick profiles for every DBMS:

**This is the profiling for every DBMS:**

```
trait Profile {
  val jdbcProfile: JdbcProfile
}

object OracleProfile extends Profile {
  override val jdbcProfile: JdbcProfile = OracleDriver
}

object H2Profile extends Profile {
  override val jdbcProfile: JdbcProfile = H2Driver
}

object PostgreSQLProfile extends Profile {
  override val jdbcProfile: JdbcProfile = PostgreSQLProfile.jdbcProfile
}
```

**And this is the Database definition:**

```
trait DBComponent {

  val jdbcProfile: JdbcProfile
  import jdbcProfile.api._
  val db: Database

}

trait OracleDB extends DBComponent {
  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  val jdbcProfile: JdbcProfile = OracleProfile.jdbcProfile
}

trait H2DB extends DBComponent {
  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  val jdbcProfile: JdbcProfile = H2Profile.jdbcProfile
}

trait PostgreSQLDB extends DBComponent {
  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  val jdbcProfile: JdbcProfile = PostgreSQLProfile.jdbcProfile
}
```

But my doubts came here: if i try to mixin the `EquivalenceOracleDB` trait that contains the Slick basics into `EquivalenceOracleRepository` also i need to mixin the component and actually i'm getting an error:

**Mixin:**

```
class EquivalenceOracleRepository extends EquivalenceRepository with EquivalenceOracleDB{
```

And the error: `Illegal inheritance, self-type EquivalenceOracleRepository does not conform to DBComponent` because of the mismatch of the interfaces. So, i need some light:

- ***Is there a known concrete Slick multi-db implementation that i can use in conjunction with the paradigm exposed by Debasish?***
- ***How could i improve the design of my concrete implementation for being compliant with the repository pattern defined in the book and also not messing the concrete and abstract implementation as of now? (keeping concerns separated)***

I have seen [the Multi-DB example that Lightbend has](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/slick-multidb-3.0), but, apart of unsolved dependency problems it relies heavily on the Cake Pattern, which is very verbose. I'm trying to stick to the book.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're getting such error is that you're not mixing `OracleDB`. You should replace:

```
class EquivalenceOracleRepository extends EquivalenceRepository with EquivalenceOracleDB
```

with

```
class EquivalenceOracleRepository extends EquivalenceRepository with EquivalenceOracleDB with OracleDB
```

Now you'll get an error that `db` is not defined, so you should provide its implementation somewhere (because it's defined as abstract in `DBComponent`). I think this could be done in `OracleDB`, which will make that trait concrete and not abstract as it is now. I think this way you'll be more or less compliant with the design presented in the book (you have an abstract interface describing your Repository, and multiple concrete/production implementations).

Comment: That was it! also, i have to say that i've asked Debasish on twitter (https://twitter.com/AlejandroM_E/status/803003856124870656) and he addressed the multi-db question with this useful post: http://leaks.wanari.com/2016/08/17/enviroment-dependent-database-drivers-slick/.